# Retrieving objects from ArrayList - cast to type?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm taking a basic course in C# programming, and this is a part of our assignment.
Very new to programming so I feel more than a bit lost with this.

The assignment is to add an `ArrayList` and insert strings from a file to this, which I hopefully have done with the code below:

- `Read ()` is a method in another class (`FileReader`) that reads the files from `"info.txt"` and returns an `ArrayList`.
- The `ArrayList` items are supposed to store the object items, although I'm not quite sure why I need two arrays?

The problem I have is: when you retrieve the "items" from the array, they have to be cast to a type, `string`, (if I understand it correctly, otherwise they are returned as `objects`?). How do I do that?

Can you cast the entire `ArrayList`?

```
public PriceFlux ()  //Constructor
{
    ArrayList items;          
    items = new ArrayList();
    FileReader infoFile = new FileReader("info.txt"); 
    items = infoFile.Read();   
}
```

The files from the `info.txt` looks approximately like this:

> G&34&Kellogs K frukostflingor&Sverige&29.50&5/11/2005&29/10/2005&29/10/2006

Here is the `FileReader Read()` method:

```
public ArrayList Read ()
{
    ArrayList fileContent = new ArrayList ();
    try
    {                               
        while (line != null)
        {   
            fileContent.Add (line);
            line = reader.ReadLine ();
        }
        reader.Close ();
    } 
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Couldn´t read from file.");
    }
    return fileContent;
}
```

Very grateful for suggestions on how to solve this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use linq to do this easily:

This will cast all items to `string` and return an `IEnumerable<string>`. It will fail if any items can't be cast to a `string`:

```
items.Cast<string>();
```

This will cast all items that can be to a `string` and skip over any that can't:

```
items.OfType<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access single elements in the `ArrayList` doing a cast, for example...

```
string s = myArrayList[100] as string;
myArrayList.Remove("hello");
myArrayList[100] = "ciao"; // you don't need a cast here.
```

You can also iterate through all elements without a cast...

```
foreach (string s in myArrayList)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

You can also use `CopyTo` method to copy all items in a string array...

```
string[] strings = new string[myArrayList.Count];
myArrayList.CopyTo(strings);
```

You can create another `List<string>` with all items in the `ArrayList`.
Since `ArrayList` implements `IEnumerable` you can call the `List<string>` constructor.

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>(myArrayList);
```

But this doesn't makes much sense... why you don't just use `List<string>` directly?
Using directly a `List<string>` seems more useful to me, and is faster.
`ArrayList` still exists mostly for compatibility purposes since generics were introduced in version 2 of the language.

I just noticed that there may be an error in your code:

```
    while (line != null)
    {   
        fileContent.Add (line);
        line = reader.ReadLine ();
    }
```

Should be instead

```
    for (;;)
    {   
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (line == null)
            break;
        fileContent.Add(line);
    }
```

Comment: Sure, but Maybe the idea is to teach them how you can exploit the Object class for this stuff in C#/.NET. After all its a home work assignment.

Comment: In the assignment we have to use ArrayList, I did read that it might be better to use List<string> though...               Thankyou for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You cast each element on its own before using it.